# Where clause has OR In Sphinx

Tags: mysql, sql, sphinx

Is there a way to do this line in sphinx search

```
where field_a = 'Value' or field_b = 'Value'
```

I have tried so far

```
$sphinx->where(field_A | field_B, '=', 'Value')
```

But it's not working.
Could someone help me to get over this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sphinx itself does not support 'OR' in the WHERE clause.

But can do something like

```
SELECT id, (attribute_a = 'Value' OR attribute_b = 'Value') AS test
FROM index
WHERE test = 1
```

It's a little convoluted, but does work. Also no idea what library you using to build the query, so left as an exercise to how to construct a SQL query like above.

(Also note I changed to call the column, attributes instead. Sphinx treats attributes and fields very differently. Clarifying this is a way of filtering **attributes**)

Comment: Hi, barry. I guess write a queyr like above will lead a full scan of the attribtes. It's may be performance drop even if they are all stored in memory. I'm not sure if I simply write "SELECT id FROM index WHERE attribute_a = 1;", could sphinx make a fast indexed lookup to find all records with "attribute_a = 1" (may be through a Red–black tree or hash map)? Or it still need a memory full scan even with this simple query? Thanks :-)

Comment: Note that in sphinx, attribute based queries are ALWAYS 'full scans'. **The attribute filters will be run against every row**. There are no attribute indexes. (the full-text query on the other hand DOES use a special index, that is kinda of the whole point of sphinx, its magic inverted index for running fast text queries. If concerned about performance of filters, implement via fields. will *normally** be faster than attributues)

Comment: Thanks for your nice tips barry :-), So **filtering or sorting by attributes in sphinx will always be implemented by "full scan"**. The only thing we can optimize the query performance is create a corresponding  text field to let sphinx using its full inverted index like: `MATCH('@attr_a 1|2|3')`? Or Could we create a UDF plugin, maintain a fast index in it, and let sphinx use this plugin to do the attributes query and sorting? Just like what we have been done to solve this problem: http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=14391

Comment: Dont think UDF will help, the UDF will be called on every matching row anyway, so can't really be any quicker than sphinx just accessing the attribute. While its in theory possibly the UDF could be more efficent than the attribute lookup, its unlikely. And UDFs definitly cant do 'index scans' to help with sorting. SPhinx does real sorting, rather than 'retriving rows that happen to be in the right order.

Comment: Ok, hope there will be a new type of plugin supported by sphinx to let user interpose the filtering and sorting of attributes. :-)